# Android dialog activity takes out the whole screen instead of a dialog

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to set up an activity that pretends to be a dialog.
I want it to appear in the middle of the screen, but it takes the whole screen instead, showing just gray...

I used relativeLayout, here is my code and a screenshot -

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
tools:context=".TodoListManagerActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/et_add_dialog_text"
    android:hint="@string/addDialogInsertTextHere"
    />

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:id="@+id/dp_add_dialog_date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_add_dialog_text" />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add!"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_dialog_add"
        android:layout_below="@id/dp_add_dialog_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dp_add_dialog_date"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/addDialogCheckBoxNoDueDate"
    android:id="@+id/cbx_add_dialog_no_due"
    android:layout_below="@id/dp_add_dialog_date"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_dialog_cancel"
    android:layout_below="@id/dp_add_dialog_date"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/dp_add_dialog_date"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and a screenshot (the wasted place was marked in yellow) - 
[screenshot of the fullscreen activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pztGF.jpg)

I searched in the net and praticularly at stackoverflow.com, all of the other rellevant questions that were asked had somewhere "alignParentLeft" + "alignParentRight" with two components or so, but I couldn't find such a thing in my code.

Thanks in advance for you all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the theme of an Activity (that pretends to be a Dialog) as Dialog. 
Enter the below code in your manifest.

```
       <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
        >
        </activity>
```

This line is important to set your activity to pretend like a dialog box.

```
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks!

I added it first in the activity layout, didn't know it should be in the manifest as well :)

Comment: Glad it helped you.. .Mark that answer as correct if you got solution @Re'em